# Navigate.push action rendering the page multiple times

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am working on React Native Application. In my sidebar (Drawer) menu to open the categories I used

```
const pushAction = StackActions.push({
  routeName: 'CategoryList',
  params: {
    catId: 9,
  },
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
```

This logic is working fine. But, when I click on categories in drawer on first click page is rendered only minimum times that's needed. But, again when I click on drawer menu category page rendered increased by two times every time. Due to this multiple loaders are showing up. I cannot be able to find out the best solution for this problem yet.

Comment: With .push() you are mounting the same component multiple times when the same category is clicked. Try .navigate()

Comment: @SametM. Push is not working in drawer stack. navigate is working one time only even after adding the key.